# Question about the proof of $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^{n}-a^{n}}{x-a}=na^{n-1}$

Tags: limits, proof-explanation, binomial-theorem

**Proof:**

Let, $x-a=h\implies x=a+h$

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^{n}-a^{n}}{x-a}$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(a+h)^{n}-a^{n}}{h}$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^n(1+\frac{h}{a})^{n}-a^{n}}{h}$$

Since $h\to0$, $h$ can be supposed to be less than $a$. So, $|\frac{h}{a}|<1$. Therefore, $(1+\frac{h}{a})^n$ can be expanded with the help of the binomial theorem.

$$\text{rest of the proof...}$$

**Questions:**

1. Why do we need to assume that $h$ is smaller than $a$? Does this property not hold if $h$ is greater than or equal to $a$?
2. Why does $|\frac{h}{a}|<1$ need to be true for us to expand $(1+\frac{h}{a})^n$ using the binomial theorem?

Comment: The assumption $|h|<|a|$ isn't necessary for the proof if $n$ is a positive interger. I guess the writer mixed up things with series (non-interger or negative $n$).

Comment: @YvesDaoust the higher-order terms become zero anyways (after inputting h=0). So, why does $|\frac{h}{a}|$ need to be less than 1?

Comment: To make $\left|\dfrac ha\right|^{n+1}\ll\left|\dfrac ha\right|^n$. *Negligible*.

Comment: The binomial theorem doesn't need any assumption on how big or small are the terms. If  the presented proof was taken from a book, then I agree with @A.Γ. that it seems to be a sort of mix with another topics.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4271734/768162)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem lies in "$n$".

Writing the limit theorem precisely:

For any positive integer $n$, $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^{n}-a^{n}}{x-a}=na^{n-1} \tag{A}\label{A}$$ where $a$ is any non-zero real number.

Now, for proving this theorem after this step: $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^n(1+\frac{h}{a})^{n}-a^{n}}{h}$$
and after the expansion of $(1+\frac{h}{a})^n$ you are correct to say that "higher-order terms become zero anyways (after inputting h=0). So, why does $|\frac{h}{a}|$ need to be less than 1?"

Indeed $|\frac{h}{a}|<1$ is not necessary for this proof.

Also $|\frac{h}{a}|<1$ does not need to be true for us to expand $(1+\frac{h}{a})^n$ using the Binomial theorem **when $n$ is positive integer**

But perhaps you are trying to show that $(\ref{A})$ holds even when $n$ is a rational number and $a$ is positive.

Now, the binomial expansion, $$(1+x)^n= 1+ nx + \frac{n(n-1)}{ 2!}x^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3+\cdots \tag{B}\label{B}$$ is true for all rational number $n$ (and has infinite no. of terms when $n \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{W}$) **only when $|x|<1$** and certainly in this case, $|\frac{h}{a}|<1$ is true, so yes $(\ref{A})$ holds even when $n$ is rational.

Note that, the binomial expansion $(\ref{B})$ is true when $n$ is a positive integer (and has exactly $n+1$ terms) regardless of $|x|$ being less than or greater than or equal to $1$.

Comment: $\mathbb{W}=\mathbb{Z}^+ \cup \{0\}$ is the set of whole numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer!! Extra question: can we apply the above formula to this: $$\lim_{x\to -2} \frac{x^2-(-2)^2}{x+2}$$? I get the correct answer by using the above formula, but you said $a$ has to be a positive real number, so I'm confused.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Yes, when $n$ is a positive integer, $a$ can be any real number. You can see in the proof $a$ being negative doesn't make any difference when $n$ is positive integer but $a>0$ is required when $n$ is any rational number other than whole number.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote $a$ is positive real number everywhere because I was trying to limit my focus to $n$ but now I have edited my answer to make it more generalised so as to cover your extra question. I hope you are not confused now and you can see that the answer without edit had no problem either, it's just that I didn't include the case when a is negative.

Comment: Also, $a=0$ is fine unless $n \neq 1$. So, for any positive integer $n$, $a$ should be non-zero

Comment: So, for any positive integer or rational number, $a$ has to be non-zero. The only exception is when $n=1$, right?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic $a$ has to be non-zero when $n=1$ because when $n=1$, RHS of (A), i.e., $a^0$ would be undefined at $a=0$ however the limit exists and is equal to 1. When $n \neq1 \; (n \in \Bbb Z^+)$, $a$ can be any real number including zero. You can verify that the limit will be zero and so will be the RHS for $a=0$ when $n \in \{2,3,4,\ldots\}$.

Comment: Coming to the case when $n$ is any rational number, $a$ has to be non-zero again here. You can check what happens at $n=0$ or $n=0.5$ or any negative $n$ in (A) if $a=0$. Therefore better to have non-zero $a$ always (also because the special case of $a=0$ trivial in itself that you don't have to use this formula for calculating the limit.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comments!!!! I had a question: you earlier said that if $n$ is a positive integer, then $a$ can be any real number (including zero). However, if $a = 0$, then $\frac{h}{a}=\frac{h}{0}$ becomes undefined; doesn't our proof become invalid then?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic Man, What I said earlier was "if $n$ is a positive integer and $n\neq 1$ then $a$ can be any real number including zero **in (A)** ". I never said the same proof will work for this trivial case of $a=0$. Isn't it obvious that when $a=0$,  $ \small \lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{x^{n}-a^{n}}{x-a}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{x^{n}}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x^{n-1} =0 \;(\because n\in \{2,3,4, \ldots\})$ which is equal to the RHS of (A), i.e., $n 0^{n-1}=0$. Now why would you go for a binomial proof?And how would $a+h$ be equal to $a(1+\frac{h}{a})$ when $a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

Use
$x^n-a^n
=(x-a)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^ka^{n-1-k}
$.

Then,
if
$0 < a-c < x < a+c$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^ka^{n-1-k}\\
\text{so}\\ 
\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}
&\lt\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(a+c)^ka^{n-1-k}\\
&\lt \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(a+c)^{n-1}\\
&=n(a+c)^{n-1}\\
\text{and}\\
\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}
&\gt\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(a-c)^ka^{n-1-k}\\
&\gt \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(a-c)^{n-1}\\
&=n(a-c)^{n-1}\\
\end{array}
$

I'll work with
the first inequality here.
The second is similar.

If $0 < z < 1$
then
$(1+z)^m
=1+\sum_{j=1}^m \binom{m}{j}z^j
\le 1+\sum_{j=1}^m \binom{m}{j}z
=1+(2^m-1)z
$

so
$(1+z)^m-1
\le (2^m-1)z
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}-na^{n-1}
&\lt n(a+c)^{n-1}-na^{n-1}\\
&=na^{n-1}((1+c/a)^{n-1}-1)\\
\text{so if } c<a\\
\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}-na^{n-1}
&\lt na^{n-1}((1+c/a)^{n-1}-1)\\
&\lt na^{n-1}(2^{n-1}-1)(c/a)\\
\end{array}
$

so if
$c < \dfrac{a\epsilon}{na^{n-1}(2^{n-1}-1)}
$
(remembering that
$x < a+c$)

then
$\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}-na^{n-1}
\lt \epsilon
$.